# How to change the dpi of differently sized images within a pdf in order to realise a common "print size" for every page?

Tags: pdf, printing, imagemagick, dpi, imagemagick-convert

I am new to the world of raster images, so I will first explain which definitions I use and hope that I will use them right:
- geometry (the total number of pixels of the image %w * %h)
- resolution (pixels per inch / ppi)
- size or "print size" (the display size (e.g. in inches) on screen or printer)

I have some PDF documents containing raster images of different geometry. When opening with evince they therefore all display (and I guess potentially print) with different sizes. I would like to define the print size within the pdf so that evince (or any other viewer) would display every page with the same size when opening the document.

How could this be realized? Geometry and print size of the image are linked by the resolution  as far as I understand. Currently one of my pdf's shows to following *ImageMagick:identify* output:

$identify -units PixelsPerInch -format "%w x %h - %[resolution.x] x %[resolution.y] - %[fx:w/72] x %[fx:h/72] in\n" example.pdf

geometry  -  resol. -    print size  -
 538 x  375 - 72 x 72 -  7.47 x  5.20 in
 546 x  381 - 72 x 72 -  7.58 x  5.29 in
1210 x 1681 - 72 x 72 - 16.80 x 23.34 in
1658 x 1166 - 72 x 72 - 23.02 x 16.19 in
 542 x  365 - 72 x 72 -  7.52 x  5.06 in
1673 x 1169 - 72 x 72 - 23.23 x 16.23 in

I would like to realize a constant print size (column 3) and I do not want to change the geometry of the image/ avoid to re-compress it, so that it does not loose quality. In order to proceed it seems to me that I need to understand the following which I cannot find any information about:

1) Which of these three values is actually saved in the pdf document and which one is calculated by *identify*?

2) Which software (and how) would allow me to batch process a number of pdf files in order to achieve my goal.

3) Guessing that geometry and resol are values of the pdf file and print size is derived from it, the software would need to calculate a resolution value for each image so that print size would qual over all pages?

Thank you very much!
Cheers,
Benjamin

Comment: Sounds to me like the pdf is broken during creation. Maybe you could recreate them? How many documents are we talking about? Manual correction might be a simpler solution...

Comment: Its about 50 documents. They were all created with different scanners and different scanning options. I add pages to them over time (timespan is years), so thats why the geometry/ resolution of the pages varies. They cannot be recreated as the original do not exists anymore but I dont think that it is broken.

Comment: 'Constant print size' means either images will be distorted, or padded with, say, white. Plus, auto-rotate, is it allowed or not. If padding and auto-rotate are OK, it's as simple as `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA -o out.pdf -f in.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think only the first two are actually stored in the PDF, but the third value (print size) is directly related to resolution (538x375) and pixel density (72ppi aka 72dpi), so it can easily be calculated anyway.

2) It seems like you're going about this a little backward. There are plenty of applications that are perfectly suited to controlling image layout and printing. Adobe Illustrator is one of the most common and there are some free ones, too. But these are going to involve loading the images, visually arranging them on the page and adjusting the print sizes visually, rather than programmatically.

2) If you did want to do this programmatically, though, I think you're going to have a hard time finding software to solve that problem. GIMP and Photoshop both have some batching capability, and I know GIMP has a fairly robust CLI, so you might be able to use that.

3) Yes, you'll start with the print size you want, divide the number of pixels by the number of inches to get ppi/dpi.

NOTE: Keep in mind that dpi goes both directions. If you have a 200 x 300 image and a 400 x 400 image, and you want them both to print 10 inches square, then you're going to distort the 200 x 300 image, stretching it horizontally. The 200 x 300 image will also look poorer quality than the 400 x 400, because you have fewer pixels to work with.

For these and other reasons, I highly recommend a visual approach, rather than a coding approach.

Good luck!

Comment: I continued to read about imagemagick. It's tool _convert_ is quite powerful in even batch processing pages in multiple pdf documents. It comes along with a "resize" and "density" option, where density means resolution. When I apply them to the documents and investigate the output then I find that in both cases the produced pdf still has 72dpi and the geometry has changed. Is there any way to change the density/ resolution factor to something different than 72 *without* touching the image itself? Why is it 72 anyways? :)

Comment: In short, yes there is a way. And 72dpi is a standard for printing.

I think it's worth noting that you're not really working with images. PDFs are specifically designed to be a document print medium. I find it plausible that PDFs don't support anything other than 72dpi. Or they make it hard not to use 72dpi, specifically because 72dpi is a standard resolution for print media. But that's just a guess...

That being said, PDFs are really little more than JPGs with some extra features, so it'd be relatively easy to change the DPI in GIMP without changing the geo. Not sure about batching, tho....